How do I make my C code return the error message for alphanumeric input
My code is supposed to take in a numeric score and return the grade it will receive. My code correctly returns an error message for all invalid input except alphanumeric. With alphanumeric input, it just takes the number and runs as usual. While this is an assignment, I have done the preliminary meeting with my professor and I am allowed to ask for help for this particular error.
I have tried using isdigit, isalphanum, other using other data types than float. Thank you
Here is the code:
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float score; // Declare a variable to store the score
    char grade; // Declare a variable to store the letter grade

    printf("Insert Score:  \n"); // Prompt user for input
    scanf("%f", &score); // Read the score

    // Assign a letter grade to score according to the provided standards
    if (score >= 80 && score <= 100) {
        grade = 'A';
    }
    else if (score >= 70 && score < 80) {
        grade = 'B';
    }
    else if (score >= 60 && score < 70) {
        grade = 'C';
    }
    else if (score >= 50 && score < 60) {
        grade = 'D';
    }
    else if (score >= 0 && score < 50) {
        grade = 'F';
    }
    else {
        printf("Invalid Input. Try Again. \n"); //Filter out invalid input
    }
    printf("Your score is %0.2f and your grade is %c \n", score, grade);
    //Print out grade and accompanying grade
    return 0;
}


What do you exactly want ? Accept only numeric input ?

@polozer yes, please. Decimal input is also required

It's not clear to me how you're using isdigit and (I assume) isalnum. If you've already taken in the float, you can't use those functions. If you want to check that there isn't something that follows the number, then you'll either need a scanf format that looks for that input, then make sure you don't get anything there, or you'll need to implement your own number input character-by-character.

And what exactly should happen if the user enters letters?

You need to clarify what input the program should accept and what the output should be

@Karis C. Anoruo –
I don't believe that for the alphanumeric input a1 it just takes the number and runs as usual.

You're better off using fgets() for ALL user input.

Since someone closed this question, and neither of the linked answers mention this: you can read in one character at a time with fgetc, check if it's invalid using isdigit (and also checking for - and .), then put the first valid character back with ungetc. Then you can use scanf like you were (although you should probably use double x; scanf(" %lf", &x);. Floats are for when you've got a gazillion of them and want to save memory.)  Yunnosch's answer from the second linked question is the other approach I'd consider, but it's slightly more complicated.

Personally, I prefer to read in a line at a time, and reject it entirely if it contains any invalid characters, as shown in Yunnosch's answer, but if you ever want to just filter out bogus characters, the fgetc/ungetc approach will let you do that.

@Armali if I could send you a video I would lol. My professor wants every non-valid input to return my error message

@Jabberwocky The user should get: 'Invalid Input. Try Again'

Thank you very much for being helpful @Ray but I genuinely do not know how to do this. All my coding experience is in Python and R, this assignment is my first time coding in C

@KarisC.Anoruo Yeah, sorry. I was finishing an answer with proper code samples when they closed it, but I can't put formatted code in the comments.
char buf[1024]; fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin); will read the next line of input, up to a maximum of 1023 characters.
double x; sscanf(buf, " %lf", &x); works like scanf, but it reads from the string instead of an input stream. Usually, if you google the name of a C standard library function, the first couple of links will be for C++, but since C++ includes the C standard library, those are usually still decent references.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ungetc has a decent example of ungetc and isdigit use for a problem somewhat similar to yours (they're reading characters until they read an invalid one).  Things to keep in mind: 1) C knows when strings end by placing a NUL character, '\0', at the end. Always make sure you include enough space for that. 2) When parsing the numbers, floating point numbers can contain a '-' as the first character, and up to one '.' anywhere, but the rest need to be digits (unless you accept numbers in the 6.023e23 format)
